# Error CRASH Cause: null pointer dereference Unity/firebase

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

In Unity editor, everything works perfectly however app crashes after splash screen on the phone. Here it is the error I get:

```
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH Version '2019.3.7f1 (6437fd74d35d)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH Build fingerprint: 'samsung/dream2ltexIn Unity editor, everything works perfectly however app crashes after splash screen on the phone. Here it is the error I get::24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm'
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2020-04-04 15:27:24+0300
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH pid: 1668, tid: 1704, name: UnityMain  >>> com.notoli.meji <<<
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH uid: 10409
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH Cause: null pointer dereference
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH     r0  00000000  r1  00000000  r2  cc1fde04  r3  40000000
2020.04.04 15:27:24.973 1668 1704 Error CRASH     r4  cc1fde04  r5  cc1fddec  r6  bd531ca4  r7  cc1fddec
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH     r8  00000000  r9  cfead8e0  r10 cc1fdf88  r11 c9489e30
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH     ip  edae6cf8  sp  cc1fddc8  lr  bd48bd0d  pc  bd48bc28
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH 
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH backtrace:
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #00 pc 0010bc28  /data/app/com.notoli.meji-sbhhgQXmtpr_eZ7fRCmdkw==/lib/arm/libFirebaseCppApp-6_5_0.so (firebase::database::(anonymous namespace)::MakeKey(firebase::App*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&)+8) (BuildId: c9e65d0479d62a87564f97624f1db521)
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #01 pc 0010bd09  /data/app/com.notoli.meji-sbhhgQXmtpr_eZ7fRCmdkw==/lib/arm/libFirebaseCppApp-6_5_0.so (firebase::database::Database::DeleteInternal()+120) (BuildId: c9e65d0479d62a87564f97624f1db521)
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #02 pc 0010bc05  /data/app/com.notoli.meji-sbhhgQXmtpr_eZ7fRCmdkw==/lib/arm/libFirebaseCppApp-6_5_0.so (firebase::database::Database::GetInstance(firebase::App*, char const*, firebase::InitResult*)+296) (BuildId: c9e65d0479d62a87564f97624f1db521)
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #03 pc 001014e5  /data/app/com.notoli.meji-sbhhgQXmtpr_eZ7fRCmdkw==/lib/arm/libFirebaseCppApp-6_5_0.so (Firebase_Database_CSharp_InternalFirebaseDatabase_GetInstanceInternal+28) (BuildId: c9e65d0479d62a87564f97624f1db521)
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #04 pc 00008422  <anonymous:e470c000>
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH 
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH managed backtrace:
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #00 (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.Database.Internal.DatabaseInternalPINVOKE:InternalFirebaseDatabase_GetInstanceInternal (System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,string,int&)
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #01 Firebase.Database.Internal.InternalFirebaseDatabase:GetInstanceInternal (Firebase.FirebaseApp,string,Firebase.InitResult&) <Z:\tmp\tmp.KRJyESkVRC\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\InternalFirebaseDatabase.cs:137>
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #02 Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase:GetInstance (Firebase.FirebaseApp,string) <Z:\tmp\tmp.KRJyESkVRC\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\FirebaseDatabase.cs:159>
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #03 Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase:GetInstance (Firebase.FirebaseApp) <Z:\tmp\tmp.KRJyESkVRC\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\FirebaseDatabase.cs:109>
2020.04.04 15:27:24.974 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #04 Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase:get_DefaultInstance () <Z:\tmp\tmp.KRJyESkVRC\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\FirebaseDatabase.cs:92>
2020.04.04 15:27:24.975 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #05 Database:Start () <D:\strategy - Kopya (3)\Assets\Scripts\Database.cs:28>
2020.04.04 15:27:24.975 1668 1704 Error CRASH       #06 (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
2020.04.04 15:27:25.476 1668 1704 Error CRASH Tombstone written to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.notoli.meji/files/tombstone_00
```

I'll appreciate any explanation.

Comment: There's not enough information here to really debug anything. If you can reproduce the crash in the database sample project (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/database/testapp) file an issue here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues

Comment: If not, at least post the source for Database.cs, but I don't know of an obvious way to get a null reference during GetInstance (maybe try calling CheckAndFixDepenenciesAsync?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Patrick! I made a two silly mistake which one of them was i put to closer and opener({} ) to start function(and vs never mentioned about it) and the other one is(most likely the one caused crashed) was my link to database had some extra (xxx.xxx/j/. "j" didn't suppose to be there)

Comment: I am facing same crash (not in firebase though). Can you please help out by mentioning whether your issue was in android part or unity part? I am kind of stuck on this crash.